Google authentication for automatic email send (in Airflow)
I'm an admin of my GCP project (I can create and manage anything) and I have to build a workflow in python to send emails periodically using Airflow. Our team has a User Admin account and we have bunch of service accounts.
I have a process in my DAG that before sending the emails creates a bunch of Google Forms using the Drive and Forms API with a Service Account for that
# Like this:

forms_service = build('forms', 'v1', credentials=credentials, static_discovery=False)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# [...]

Form = self.form_service.forms().create(body=body).execute()

# [...] 

# Replicate my Forms (I create a lot of forms iterating over this):
copied_form = drive_service.files().copy(fileId=templateId).execute()

After this I want to send by email the link of the forms to every recipient, with a formatted html body, but the GCP service account don't have Gmail capabilities so I have to use a User account to send the emails. I can have and authenticated User account sending the stored URL's to everybody, but problem is I need to authenticate my User account in the Airflow Worked without the Consent screen, I need to do it 100% automatically. I've been exploring Application Default Credentials (ADC) and Impersonating Service Accounts to accomplish that, but all my local tests are not pointing me good results. About the EmailOperator, I couldn't set properly a connection with another account to send the emails, only with the service account; also, the email properties in Airflow are set to the notifications and alerts email, which has nothing to do if this email.
In summary: How can I send the emails automatically with Airflow (either with EmailOperator or an authenticated credential) with an authenticated credential 100% unsupervised (every two weeks)?
Attemptives:

tried send the email with service account: error that the service account can't do it
tried set a connection with user account: airflow error - didn't find a Private Key
tried to use a SMTP email from Airflow: I couldn't set this properly,  IDK if this can work
ADC: I tried locally the credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes) but I coulnd't set properly the scopes, so I got the 403 error.


I'm unfamiliar with Airflow (and EmailOperator) but you could try sending the Gmail as part of the code that you've shown but you will need to impersonate the Gmail user (e.g. foo@email.com) by delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject("foo@email.com) and then gmail_service = build("gmail", "v1", credentials=delegated_credentials). You will need to ensure the Gmail OAuth scopes are set when you create the initial credentials.

@DazWilkin, Thank You! I'm going towards the impersonation, yes, just as you mentioned. I actually didn't know about this capability since I'm new in GCP projects. On the scopes part, do I need to login with my User Gmail OAuth to set the scopes properly at the time I execute the task? Because all these will be running async, I just would need to make sure that my "foo@gmail.com" has the permissions to run Gmail API?

You will need to ensure that the domain-wide delegate(d) Service Account is configured to permit these scopes using the Admin console (see link) and then you will need to request the Gmail OAuth scopes when you create credentials initially in your code

Google Cloud Platform by itself doesn't offer a direct solution/service for sending emails, so it might not be possible with a cloud-scoped service account alone. However, there is some general guidance for sending email from a VM instance that applies to Cloud Composer, since it also executes its tasks on GCE VMs.
In general, any email service provider can be used inside a GCP project as long as it exposes an SMTP server and is able to be configured on a port other than tcp 25 (if the server is not internal to your VPC network). Once you have that, most of the configuration will be within Airflow:

Configure a SMTP server or SMTP relay (if you want to use a Google Workspace domain)
Using Cloud Composer, configure an Airflow email backend.
Modify tasks to use the SMTP notifier to send emails within task callbacks

There is some documentation maintained by Cloud Composer on how to do this with a third-party SMTP server.
